# localStorage gets deleted on refresh react app ubuntu server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jwt, ubuntu-16.04

Hey there all I am struggling with a very strange issue, I have a react app where the user can log in and the JWT token gets saved in the local Storage so on refresh of the page the user is still logged in, and it works as it should.
But I have my server and the app running from a Ubuntu server now for production with nginx set up and on the refresh of the page the user is always logged out, although on the reload before the page is loaded in the console i can log out the token bearer.
Why can that be?
Do you guys have any tips?

Comment: Have you checked with Chrome Developer Console that the element exsits in localStorage?

Comment: Can you share some code also please?

Comment: Yes it exists when i log in but after the refresh is competed it does not anymore/